# What is the equivalent of chdir for UNIX?

Tags: bash, mac-osx, unix

I'm working on OSX 10.11.4 trying to write a simple bash script. I'm getting `command not found` when I try to use `chdir`. When I test with `which chdir` I get nothing. What's going on?

I'm using this clunky workaround...

```
alias vagrants_up='here=$(pwd) && cd ~/Vagrant && vagrant up && cd $(echo $here)'
```

Comment: Why would you expect a windows command to be available on a unix platform?

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: @JennyD I didn't know it was a Windows only command. That's basically the resolution to my question (and the explanation for why I couldn't find it in the docs).

Comment: @Jenny D says Reinstate Monica: Um, chdir IS a built-in command in C Shell.  So yes, you could expect it show up across Linux/Unix.

Comment: @BrianPreslopsky The question is tagged `bash` and specified that it's about writing a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `bash` shell, take a look at `pushd` and `popd`.  These are two very unsung commands that are helpful in cases like this.  `pushd` pushes the current working directory onto a stack and then does a `cd` to the directory you specify.  `popd` will then pop the top directory from that stack and `cd` to it.  Using these your alias would be:

```
alias vagrants_up=`pushd ~/Vagrant && vagrant up && popd`
```

These are very handy for interactive use, too.  I alias `cd` to `pushd` and `bk` to `popd` and find that my workflow is less cluttered when I only have to think of going 'b'ac'k' one or two or three directory changes that I don't have to spell out rather than typing directory names all the time.

Comment: These sound great but I don't seem to have those available either: `which pushd` returns nothing. :-(

Comment: Are you able to use those on OSX? This is the first time I've encountered core *nix commands that didn't exist in the OSX terminal.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` exist in OS X, but they're bash builtins so `which` won't find them. Try `type pushd` instead.

Comment: `which` does not resolve bash's **builtin commands** such as `pushd/popd`